# Python: Create list from variables as long as they are not None

Tags: python, list

How do I add multiple variables to a list as long as they are not `None`?

If either one of them is `None`, then only the other one should be added to the list.

```
a = "A"
b = None

list_items = [a + b]
```

Gives:

> TypeError: ("cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects",
>   u'occurred at index 0')

In the above example, the components of the list will always be `a` and `b`. I suspect a solution that can handle an arbitrary number of variables would make use of `.extend()` to empty list `[]` as long as the next added variable is not `None`. That could be useful, but what is the simplest solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function that takes arbitrary number of arguments and filters out the ones which are `None`:

```
def create_list(*args):
    return [a for a in args if a is not None]

print create_list(1, 4, None, 'a', None, 'b')
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the variable directly for None:

```
 a = "A"
 b = None

 if b != None:
     list_items = [a + b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be a list comprehension:

```
a = "A"
b = None

lst = [e for e in [a, b] if e]
```

It's a little arcane, but this should neatly return you a list of only elements that are "truthy" - i.e. not None, non-empty string, integer greater than 0, True boolean etc.